# return type covariance in protocol methods

Tags: swift, oop, protocols, covariance

Why doesn't swift support return type covarience in methods defined in protocols? e.g

```
class Base { }

class Derived : Base { }

protocol Requirement {
  var someVariable : Base { get }
}

struct MyStruct : Requirement{
 let someVariable : Derived
}
```

The compiler thorws an error that MyStruct doesn't conform to protocol Requirement. As far I know MyStruct fulfils all the requirements of LSP, so I am wondering why is this not allowed in Swift?

Answer (score 1):

Context is important here, so I don't know if this will get you what you want.

My answer is use `associatedtype`.

Start with the same setup

```
class Base { }
class Derived: Base { }
```

This time, I'll define a type in the protocol which must be some kind of `Base`.

```
protocol Requirement {
    associatedtype KindOfBase: Base
    var someVariable: KindOfBase { get }
}
```

Now you get what you want.

```
struct MyStruct: Requirement {
    let someVariable: Derived
}

struct MyStruct2: Requirement {
    let someVariable: Base
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have:

```
var requirement: Requirement?
```

and you want to assign a variable of type `Base`

```
let myBaseInstance = Base()
requirement.someVariable = myBaseInstance
```

If you look at your struct, that would not be possible, since the instance of base does not inherit from `Derived`.

**In other words**, this would not be possible (but it must be possible by definition of the protocol):

```
var requirement: Requirement? = MyStruct()
requirement.someVariable = myBaseInstance //error
```

You get an error at line 2 because someVariable must be of type `Derived`, but `myBaseInstance` is of type `Base` only and may not conform to `Derived`.